How to correctly insert in a DF using Python a JSON file which is inside a key in a "father" JSON FILE?
I'm trying to insert in a DF a JSON which is located in a key named "data" inside another JSON file by using Python, I'm reading this JSON from an API.
The original JSON is this one, and you can tell the JSON that I'm actually trying to insert in the DataFrame inside the "data" key:
{
  "header": {
    "responseId": "230e8981-636e-40bc-b64d-535d7ba27256",
    "responseTime": "2024-11-21 12:29:49.301 +0000",
    "version": "4.2.4",
    "url": "",
    "requestInfo": {
      "requestTime": "2024-11-21 12:29:49.079 +0000",
      "requestId": "1234",
      "domainName": "BR_NEGATIVE_CREDIT",
      "matchKey": "325",
      "format": "json",
      "subdomainName": "COMM_TRADE"
    }
  },
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": "325.Dspl1mJr/2gmmuGDpxiuR8tuzIt0z9bqXCpOgXnb4efYB2GdA8aPDoG1w7IJxCRHcmHz91FtHqOFUPe+Gm5JHw==.XX.2022-04-18.000000802405423.1730897105532.e2e902af7a6efac86de4a656c2bdd88872a98721eb25322259975612fcc8d9e5",
      "code": "OK",
      "message": "Record for \"325.Dspl1mJr/2gmmuGDpxiuR8tuzIt0z9bqXCpOgXnb4efYB2GdA8aPDoG1w7IJxCRHcmHz91FtHqOFUPe+Gm5JHw==.XX.2022-04-18.000000802405423.1730897105532.e2e902af7a6efac86de4a656c2bdd88872a98721eb25322259975612fcc8d9e5\" found.",
      "detail": null,
      "type": "GET",
      "level": "INFO",
      "transactionId": "230e8981-636e-40bc-b64d-535d7ba27256",
      "additionalInfo": null
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "325.Dspl1mJr/2gmmuGDpxiuR8tuzIt0z9bqXCpOgXnb4efYB2GdA8aPDoG1w7IJxCRHcmHz91FtHqOFUPe+Gm5JHw==.XX.2022-04-18.000000802405423.1730897105532.e2e902af7a6efac86de4a656c2bdd88872a98721eb25322259975612fcc8d9e5": "{\"ingestionHeader\": {\"geo\": \"BR\", \"dataDomain\": \"BR_NEGATIVE_CREDIT\", \"dataSubDomain\": \"COMM_TRADE\", \"dataViewName\": \"NPUR_BR_NEGATIVE_CREDIT_COMM_TRADE_VIEW\", \"dataViewVersion\": \"1.0.0\", \"correlationId\": \"b8703cc5-3785-4cc7-a9ba-d5bd2214c17a\", \"sourceId\": \"211949fb-64da-4b7b-8e71-ee0a88339d89\", \"regulatory\": false, \"sourceTimestamp\": 1730897571270, \"recordUUID\": \"1b165b5c-f2cd-4e4f-8dc9-16b28110cd7c\", \"sourceRecordUUID\": \"1b165b5c-f2cd-4e4f-8dc9-16b28110cd7c\", \"recordNumber\": 8, \"entityKey\": \"325\"}}"
  },
  "histories": null,
  "schemaKey": "NPUR_BR_NEGATIVE_CREDIT_COMM_TRADE_VIEW-1.0.0-Draft-9"
}

I'm trying to use the following function to insert the data into the DataFrame:
df = pd.json_normalize(data["data"])

But instead of returning the data, what is being returned is a hash value:
T2JqAQIWYXZyby5zY2hlbWHw5gF7InR5cGUiOiJyZWNvcmQiLCJuYW1lIjoiQlZTQ25zbXJUcmFkZSIsIm5hbWVzcGFjZSI6ImNvbS5lcXVpZmF4LmJ2cy5uZWdhdGl2ZS5tb2RlbCIsImZpZWxkcyI6W3sibmFtZSI6ImluZ2VzdGlvbkhlYWRlciIsInR5cGUiOnsidHlwZSI6InJlY29yZCIsIm5hbWUiOiJJbmdlc3Rpb25IZWFkZXIiLCJuYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJjb20uZXF1aWZheC5mYWJyaWMuaW5nZXN0aW9uLmNvbW1vbnMuZG9tYWluIiwiZmllbGRzIjpbeyJuYW1lIjoiZ2VvIiwidHlwZSI6eyJ0eXBlIjoic3RyaW5nIiwiYXZyby5qYXZhLnN0cmluZyI6IlN0cmluZyJ9fSx7Im5hbWUiOiJkYXRhRG9tYWluIiwidHlwZSI6eyJ0eXBlIj

When I try to use the Bruno Application to test it, the data is returned completly fine.
Is there a way to load this JSON located in this data key in a DF ?
I'm trying to load a JSON file from an API using Python, but instead of returning the actual data, it has been returning a hash value.

Is this how you get it from the API? That's problematic, because the value of the sub key has an invalid JSON string. I.e., it ends with \"325}}", but it should end with \"325\"}}".

My mistake, it does end with "325"}}". Do you think Bruno has some kind of background setup to automatically convert from this base64 encryption to JSON ?

Here's one approach:
import pandas as pd
import json

json_file = 'data.json'

with open(json_file, 'r') as file:
    json_data = json.load(file)

data = json.loads(*json_data['data'].values())

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Output:
                                          ingestionHeader
geo                                                    BR
dataDomain                             BR_NEGATIVE_CREDIT
dataSubDomain                                  COMM_TRADE
dataViewName      NPUR_BR_NEGATIVE_CREDIT_COMM_TRADE_VIEW
dataViewVersion                                     1.0.0
correlationId        b8703cc5-3785-4cc7-a9ba-d5bd2214c17a
sourceId             211949fb-64da-4b7b-8e71-ee0a88339d89
regulatory                                          False
sourceTimestamp                             1730897571270
recordUUID           1b165b5c-f2cd-4e4f-8dc9-16b28110cd7c
sourceRecordUUID     1b165b5c-f2cd-4e4f-8dc9-16b28110cd7c
recordNumber                                            8
entityKey                                             325

Explanation

Use json.load to load the JSON file.
The value for the sub key is a JSON string. Access it via json_data['data'].values() and unpack (*) for use in json.loads.
Pass the result to pd.DataFrame.


Edit:
@juanpa-arrivillaga correctly points out that unpacking with * is a bit of an anti-pattern, as this will work only because "data" has exactly one sub key. It will be cleaner to get the value for that key from "messages":
data = json.loads(json_data['data'][json_data['messages'][0]['id']])

Or to turn dict.values into a list and access the first element:
data = json.loads(list(json_data['data'].values())[0])


I'm fairly certain json.loads(*json_data['data'].values()) will not work

Ah, this only works because the iterable has precisely one value. This would not be the way I would do this, though

@juanpa.arrivillaga: thanks for the comments; added two better ways to reach the value.
